# first rowwidget data copy to all other rowidgets in extjs grid when selected first record

Tags: extjs, widget, grid, row

I have a situation, where i created rowwidget and this row widget contains some combo and text fields.
Lets assume my grid have 3 records and I selected or expanded my row widget and selected some data in combo. Then it should prompt saying that do you want to apply this change to all other records.(So that I can copy this first record combo value to all other records without manually enetering/selecting).Please suggest if any possibilities

I could not find any solution as of now